# Creating makefile for C code, running without ./

Tags: c, unix, makefile

I need to create a makefile that will compile my `simpleprogram.c` to `sp` and it can be called like unix commands like `ls`,`ps` etc, without writing explicitly `./sp`. I looked upon the web and cannot find a solution, or searching it in a wrong way. I cannot search like "executable without ./" , because I do not know what is this called => "`./`"

Comment: @asaelr ps is an example, from unix commands, the one that shows processes. sp is the thing i want, making simpleprgram.c to complile to sp that can be used by just typing sp in that folder.

Comment: `.` is called the *current directory* or *working directory* or *current working directory*, which is also the reason behind commands like `cwd` (in FTP) and `pwd` (on shell).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put the binary in a directory that's in your `PATH`.

http://www.cs.purdue.edu/homes/cs348/unix_path.html

Comment: But when I am in the same directory with it, shouldn't it work?

Comment: No, only with `./sp` if you're in the same directory.

Comment: What was that quote about those who fail to study history being doomed to repeat its mistakes?

Answer (score 1):

Just copy your program to your systems bin (executable binaries) directory.

Most commonly its `/usr/bin` for programs which can be used by all user.

If the app is only for admins, you should use `/usr/sbin/` directory.

Remember to set the "**executable**" flag with chmod: `chmod +x your_app`

Answer (score 1):

The proper solution to this (assuming you don't want `sp` to be run from outside of your makefile) is to call your program using the full path name instead of `./` (which is relative, and can change during multi-directory makes).  In your makefile do something like:

```
SP_DIR := $(shell pwd)/spdir

rule : somedependency
    $(SP_DIR)/sp
```

Where `$(shell pwd)` will expand to the directory the makefile is being run from.  If your sp directory is in a parent directory of this, it is possible to use `..` in the path as well:  eg.

```
SP_DIR := $(shell pwd)/../../spdir
```

If you do want to run sp from outside of the makefile, then you need to either copy sp to a directory specified in your PATH variable (do `echo $PATH` to see these), or modify your .bashrc or equivalent file to make PATH include the directory that sp is built in.

John

Answer (score 0):

You can just do:

```
export PATH=$PATH:.
```

**But this is not a good idea, in general.**

Comment: As you note, this is not a good idea. Indeed, I'd note that this is a truly terrible idea. :)